# what does this line do in perl my %input=CTRL()->{cgi}->Vars;

Tags: perl, hash

What does this line do in perl?

```
my %input=CTRL()->{cgi}->Vars;
```

I don't really understand whats going on here. My best assumption is that `Vars` is the key and we are inserting those key-value pairs into the input hash.

Answer (score 2):

It's called `CTRL`. This function returns a reference to a hash. It access the element with keys `cgi` of this hash. It appears to be an instance of [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI). It calls the `Vars` method of that object.

> Many people want to fetch the entire parameter list as a hash in which the keys are the names of the CGI parameters, and the values are the parameters' values. The Vars() method does this. Called in a scalar context, it returns the parameter list as a tied hash reference. Changing a key changes the value of the parameter in the underlying CGI parameter list. Called in a list context, it returns the parameter list as an ordinary hash. This allows you to read the contents of the parameter list, but not to change it.
>
> When using this, the thing you must watch out for are multivalued CGI parameters. Because a hash cannot distinguish between scalar and list context, multivalued parameters will be returned as a packed string, separated by the "\0" (null) character. You must split this packed string in order to get at the individual values. This is the convention introduced long ago by Steve Brenner in his cgi-lib.pl module for perl version 4, and may be replaced in future versions with array references.